# Сжатие UIView при показе клавиатуры

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, как сжать UIView  при открытии клавиатуры

Вот у меня такой UIViewController

[image]

[image]

При открытии клавиатуры мне необходимо сжать UITableView и поднять UIView (Синего цвета)

Answer (score 1):

Я вот так делал (настройте для своего случая):

```
#pragma mark Table View frame
- (void)updateScrollViewFrameAnimated:(BOOL)animated
                   forKeyboardVisible:(BOOL)visible
{
    CGRect mainFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat animationTime = animated?ANIMATION_TIME:0.0f;
    CGFloat height = mainFrame.size.height - self.tableView.frame.origin.y;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(
                              self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                              self.tableView.frame.origin.y,
                              self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                              visible?height - KEYBOARD_HEIGHT:height);

    __weak typeof(self) wself = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationTime
                     animations:^{
                         wself.tableView.frame = frame;
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Подпрыгивает, нашел решение вот тут
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043371/resize-a-view-when-a-keyboard-appears-ios

Так же пришлось использовать на storyboard pin, чтобы закрепить нижнюю вьюшку к низу родной вью.

Comment: Ээ, не совсем понял - то, что я написал у вас не работает?

ЗЫ: хорошо, что решили свою проблему)

Answer (score 0):

подписываешься 
вот так

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

и внутри достаешь рект клавы и анимацией или без меняешь констрейнт какой тебе надо, например у тебя констрейнт низ вьюхи и низ экрана то при открытии к нему добавляешь высоту при закрытии вычитаешь

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
CGRect keyboardEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect convertedEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEnd fromView:nil];

// Convert the Keyboard Animation to an Option, note the << 16 in the option
UIViewAnimationCurve keyAnimation = [userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

// Change the Height or Y Contraint to the new value.
self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.height - convertedEnd.origin.y;
[UIView animateWithDuration:[userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                      delay:0.0
                    options:keyAnimation << 16
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 } completion:nil];
```